# Select multiples values in multiples columns

Tags: java, mysql, search

I'm developing a little warehouse management software in Java and I have a problem while I'm trying to search some values in 3 columns.

The table is this:

### Products

- id
- code
- rawCode
- initials
- description
- family
- warehouseStock

I need to search a string separated by spaces. Ex.

Search String: "mirror 120 5269"

Where "5269" is part of the code and "miror 120" is part of the description.

I tried this and a fulltext index

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE (PRODUCTS.code OR PRODUCTS.description OR PRODUCTS.family)
LIKE '%mirror 120 5269%'
```

Comment: `WHERE CONCAT(A, B, C) LIKE '% query %''`. Note, this **won't** be fast. If you want this to be remotely performant, you need another column that has those values put together in it - and even then it won't be particularly performant. If you need to join on space, then `CONCAT_WS(' ', A, B, C)`

Comment: Split the string in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT operator as follows

```
SELECT *  FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE CONCAT(code, ' ',description) LIKE %your-string%
```

This will  give you all rows having same string in  code column space description column

Comment: This works fine when I put the Sting in order (code, descr. family), but not if I change the order to for example (family, descr., code) SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p WHERE CONCAT(p.code, ' ',p.description, ' ', p.family) LIKE '%5269%mirror%NW%'

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT Function to merge the string of what you are going to search

I didn't test it but it could be like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CONCAT(PRODUCTS.code + ' ' + PRODUCTS.description) LIKE '%mirror 120 5269%'"
```

Comment: This works fine when I put the Sting in order (code, descr. family), but not if I change the order to for example (family, descr., code)
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE CONCAT(p.code, ' ',p.description, ' ', p.family)
LIKE '%5269%mirror%NW%'

Comment: @freaker that’s because the like function is in order with code + ‘ ‘ + description... You can also manage to search it with “SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTS.code LIKE ‘%-String-%’ OR PRODUCTS.description LIKE ‘%-String-%’ “ so that it will search any match between the two columns but you can’t be allowed to complete the search... With this query you can only search for description only or code only...

Comment: `CONCAT(PRODUCTS.code + ' ' + PRODUCTS.description)` is not valid syntax.